# Error thrown inside generator finishes it despite being caught

Tags: javascript, error-handling, generator

I have an async generator function, which inside calls few async functions which can throw errors. What I want is that when error occurs, generator just logs it but then continue to work further. So i have a code like this...

```
async * getAll (somestuff) {
  try {
    const thing = await fetchThing()
    const otherThing = await fetchAnother()

    yield {
      ...thing,
      ...otherThing
    }
  } catch (error) {
    console.log('Error happened, but thats ok, I want to continue')
  }
}
```

But when error occurs, it gets logged by the catch block, but then generator yields { done: true } and operation stops.
I have tried manually yielding null after console.log in catch block but with the same result.

Comment: There is nothing else for the generator to do outside of the try-catch ... What did you expect?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This kind of "problem" is not related to the generator itself, it's just related to the `await` mechanism inside a `try..catch` block, because **whenever a promise is rejected inside a try-catch block, the `catch` is joined** (unless the promises is try-catched separetely).

In fact, the generator cannot go any further, because once the `catch` is somehow reached, it will continue until another `yield` is invoked. If none needs to be invoked, it just finishes giving `done: true`, and that's the intended behavior of a generator.

Your main issue, is that you are expecting a generator to yield all the values, but it just **can't**, because the `yield` block is **never reached**:

```
try {
    const thing = await fetchThing()
    const otherThing = await fetchAnother()

    yield { // <-- never met if either thing or otherThing are rejected.
      ...thing,
      ...otherThing
    }
  } catch (error) { // <-- this block is reached whenever either thing or otherThing raise an exception.
    console.log('Error happened, but thats ok, I want to continue')
  }
```

If you want your `try..catch` block to continue if either of the inner awaitable elements raised an exception, you need to try-catch them as well, so that you can have further control over their "failing" behavior:

```
try {
    let thing, otherThing;
    try {
       thing = await fetchThing()
       otherThing = await fetchAnother()
    }
    catch (innerException) {
       console.log('either of the above failed!', innerException);
    }
    // in this way, the below block will be reached.
    yield {
      ...thing,
      ...otherThing
    }
  } catch (error) {
    console.log('Error happened, but thats ok, I want to continue')
  }
```

In this way, whether both fails or both will be successful the `yield` block will be reached and will continue the execution.

Here is an example showing what said above:

```js
const fakeAsync = async () => await Promise.resolve(true);
const fakeAsyncReject = async () => await Promise.reject(false);

async function* getAll(someStuff) {
  try {
    let res, raiseExc;
    try {
      res = await fakeAsync();
    }
    catch (innerResException) {
      console.log('an inner exception raised.');
    }

    try {
      raiseExc = await fakeAsyncReject();
    }
    catch (innerRaiseException) {
      console.log('an inner exception was raised.', innerRaiseException);
    }
    // yield block, always reached unless there is something really wrong in this try block, like syntax errors or whatever.
    yield {
      res,
      raiseExc
    }
  }
  catch (error) {
    // catch block raised only when the try block above yields an exception, NOT raised when either of the try-catch blocks inside the try-catch actually join the catch.
    console.log('Error happened', error);
  }
}

// Uncomment this block if you want to see how the for-await would work.
/*
(async() => {
for await (var res of getAll([])) {
console.log('res is', res);
}
})();
*/

(async() => {
  const asyncIterator = getAll([]);
  console.log(await asyncIterator.next());
})();
```

Comment: Finally it seems to work, I need to contemplate on this and read some more. Thank you very much for explaining it @briosheje! One more thing, if code needs to get to the yield keyword to continue, I wonder why did catch () { yield null } not work?

Comment: You're welcome, remember that every **unhandled** promise reject will cause that behavior, hence you should handle that even if you're looping an array of promises ;). Hope this made things clear, though.