# Re-try async generator after catching an error

Tags: javascript

Suppose I have async generator (which creates iterator):

```
   // infinite data processing 
   async function* createDataProcessingIterator() {
      try {
        while (true) {
          const { data: { items }} = await axios.get(API_URL);
          const processedData = processData(items);

          yield processedData;
        }
      } catch (err) {
        console.log('Error while iterating: ', err);
      }
    }

    const dataProcessingIterator = createDataProcessingIterator();

    for await (const data of dataProcessingIterator) {
      // manage processed data
    }
```

And it works fine, except when I catch an error (for example from the API server). In this case my iterator just stops. How to proceed iteration flow after catching an error?

Comment: I this one should answer your question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57458966/error-thrown-inside-generator-finishes-it-despite-being-caught?rq=1

Comment: Your generator ends because you do not `yield` anything inside `catch`.